# code splitting with dynamic imports with typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, webpack, code-splitting

I am really struggling to find any good examples for typescript and code splitting.

There are babel plugins that cover this but really thin on the ground for typescript examples.

I am using react so I would like to use `React.Lazy` but I cannot find anything that covers the webpack code splitting side of things

I did find this [old example](https://github.com/xugao/webpack-typescript-react-loadable-example) but it uses the now deceased CommonsChunkPlugin:

```
plugins: [
    new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
        name: "vendor",
        minChunks: function (module) {
          // this assumes your vendor imports exist in the node_modules directory
          return module.context && module.context.includes("node_modules");
        }
      })
],
```

It uses [react-loadable](https://github.com/jamiebuilds/react-loadable) but obviously cannot use the babel plugin so the example is manually adding the magic webpack comments:

```
export const LoadableHello = Loadable({
    loader: () => import(/* webpackChunkName: "hello" */ "./Hello"),
    loading: () => <div>loading ...</div>
});
```

Can anyone help me understand:

1. How can I setup codesplitting for dynamic imports in the webpack side of things:
2. Can I use React.Lazy with typescript?

I think I need to make sure ts is not removing the comments.

Comment: I've used `React.lazy` in a Typescript projects. It works fine!

Comment: can you point me to an example of how to set up the webpack?  Knowing you can do it just makes me all the more jealous :)

Comment: I'm not entirely familiar with configuring webpack for dynamic importing - I thought it was something that was supported out of the box. Taking a quick peak at their documentation would seem to confirm this: https://webpack.js.org/guides/code-splitting/#dynamic-imports Have you tried just using `React.lazy` and a dynamic import like: `const Component = React.lazy(() => import('./Component'));` assuming your React version is 16.6 +

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer was to ensure these values were set in my tsconfig.json:

```
"compilerOptions": {
    "jsx": "react",
    "lib": ["es5", "es2015", "es2016", "dom", "es2015.promise"],
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node"
  },
```

I then need to add the magical webpack comment to any lazy import, maybe you don't need to do this if you are using babel and typescript:

```
const TreeContainer = React.lazy(() =>
  import(/*
  webpackChunkName: "tree-container",
  webpackPrefetch: true
*/ '../TreeContainer')
);
```

This only worked on webpack `4.28.4`.  `4.29.x` did not work.

Comment: it is not working for me https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60056219/how-to-use-dynamic-import-in-typescript-with-webpack-application

Answer (score 0):

webpack above version 2 supports Dynamic import works out of the box.

if you really interested in seeing some example try to install CRA with typescript support with this command.
`npx create-react-app my-app --typescript`.

then browse to `node_module` and open `react-sctipts` package and browse to config folder and there you can find webpack config for both develop and production.

Answer (score 0):

Using `create-react-app` with Typescript there was no setup needed. You can take examples from the [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/code-splitting.html#reactlazy). E.g.

```js
import React, { Suspense, lazy } from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';

const Home = lazy(() => import('./routes/Home'));
const About = lazy(() => import('./routes/About'));

const App = () => (
  <Router>
    <Suspense fallback={<div>Loading...</div>}>
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/" component={Home}/>
        <Route path="/about" component={About}/>
      </Switch>
    </Suspense>
  </Router>
);
```